# pg_restore raising errors that require clarification

Tags: postgresql

A number of errors are being generated when calling `pg_restore -c -d app_development -Fc [...]`

Some are straightforward, but others leave space for doubts (in this reader's mind)
Most seem to be derived from the fact that on one server, the user is `welcome` and on the second server the usr is `deploy`

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
Command was: DROP EXTENSION plpgsql;

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
[...]
pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
```

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgrestore.html) refers to two commands `-O` and `--no-owner` command.
The documentation states `With -O, any user name can be used for the initial connection, and this user will own all the created objects.` which appears to resolve this ownership substitution in the restore process, but I remain uncertain, as no example is provided. (and which of the two is to use, where?)
`pg_restore -c -d -O` 
leads to error `pg_restore: error: too many command-line arguments`

Comment: You can use `--no-privileges` to skip restoring privileges

Comment: Would it not be easier to just add the `welcome` user to the second server?

Comment: `-O` and `--no-owner` are just the long and the short names for the same thing.

Comment: On what version does `pg_restore -c -d -O` lead to "pg_restore: error: too many command-line arguments" ?

Comment: This is occuring on an installation with version 12.